# SSIS how to close connections after task completion

Tags: postgresql, ssis, odbc

I'm using SSIS 2013; I connect to some databases, using ODBC and postgreSQL source connectors, to retrieve data, but the sessions that are opened in those databases, seem to stay open for over an hour.
Is there a way to force SSIS to close the connections after a task is completed?

I read from another thread that the closing is done automatically, so I guess maybe it's done after the completion of the whole package?
Is there a way to make it close after the completion of single tasks?

I tried to change the option RetainSameConnection but wasn't able to solve anything, because I have tasks which are executed in parallel and so they can't use just one session, because they need one for each task.

Thanks

Comment: If you are using SSIS built in tools, it should close all connections.  If you have custom built script tasks using C# or something else, you should make sure to close the connections yourself in those processes.